# How to sanitize user password information in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm capturing username, email and password in a custom registration form on my WordPress site.  I'm sanitising the username using `sanitize_user()` and `sanitize_email()` sanitises the email address.

For example:

```
$username = sanitize_user( $username );
$email = sanitize_email( $email );
```

How should I sanitise the password entered by the user? All I can think of is `sanitize_text_field( $pass )` but I'm sure that isn't the right way to do it.

Ref:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_user
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_email

Comment: ___Why___ should you sanitize the password? If I create an account using a strong password, I don't want a site to weaken it for me

Comment: I assumed you sanitize everything in case someone was trying to inject something nasty into the database?

Comment: The password is hashed by `wp_insert_user()`. Is that enough?

Comment: hashing is enough... the generated hash creates a string containing only characters that are valid for insertion into a database (no quotes, etc) and nothing nasty that can be added to the database

Answer (score 4):

Sanitizing won't necessarily protect you from injection. To protect against that you need to use prepared statements - or in the case of WordPress, use the [$wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Sanitization simply strips invalid characters, in the cases you've given above, it removes characters not allowed in usernames, or are not allowed in a valid email address. Passwords allow lots of different character types because that's what makes them 'strong' so you don't want to strip them out.

If you're using [`wp_insert_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) to create a WP User, then you don't need to sanitize any of it anyway, the function will take care of it all for you.

Comment: Out of interest, how does `wp_insert_user()` take care of sanitization?

Comment: You can see it in [core](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/user.php#L0). It uses `sanitize_user()` for the username and [`wp_hash_password`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password) for the password. As @Mark Barker says above, hashing a password is enough for sanitization. Of course, WP handles the database insertion correctly so there is no chance of injection - which I believe was your initial concern.

Comment: I noticed `sanitize_user()` and `wp_hash_password()` in core. I didn't notice anything associated with sanitizing the email address. Did I miss that? Or is the user's email inserted into the database unsanitized?

Comment: its stil a good idea to limit the amount of charaters of the password field in the registration and login process.

Comment: Looking through wp_insert_user, it looks like you still need to do your own sanitizing for fields like first_name, last_name, user_email, display_name, and a variety of others depending on which fields you are submitting.

Answer (score 2):

### [`wp_insert_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/) state of sanitization and filters as off (2021) WordPress `5.7`

---

**[`wp_insert_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/) and `user_pass` by default:**

- Hash `user_pass` via [`wp_hash_password()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_hash_password/).

> Should NOT be sanitized.

---

**[`wp_insert_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/) and `user_login` by default:**

- Sanitize `user_login` via [`sanitize_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_user/).
- Filter `user_login` via [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).
- Filter `user_login` via [`mb_strlen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php). (60 characters maximum).
- Compare `user_login` via [`username_exists()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/username_exists/) to users.
- Compare `user_login` via [`illegal_user_logins`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/illegal_user_logins/) to illegal user logins.

---

**[`wp_insert_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/) and `user_nicename` by default:**

- Sanitize `user_nicename` via [`sanitize_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_user/).
- Filter `user_nicename` via [`mb_strlen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php). (50 characters maximum).
- Sanitize `user_nicename` via [`sanitize_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_user/).

---

**[`wp_insert_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/) and `user_email` by default:**

- **No distinct sanitization.**
- Filter `user_email` via [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).
- Compare `user_email` via [`strcasecmp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) to old.
- Compare `user_email` via [`email_exists()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/email_exists/) to old.

---

**[`wp_insert_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/) and `user_url`, `display_name`, `nickname`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `last_name`, `description`, by default:**

- **No distinct sanitization.**
- **No distinct filters.**
- **No distinct comparison.**

---

### Sources

- `user.php` @ https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/user.php

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you can use the `sanitize_text_field()` function. It may cause some issues on some crazy passwords with special characters etc.

But it should be okay.

Comment: You do not need to sanitize the password field for WordPress as wp_insert_user or wp_update_user will hash the data and this sanitizes it.


You can use `sanitize_text_field` but it would make some passwords fail and convert some %20 values to HTML entities like spaces or characters etc.